# discord bot command whois can't display user's roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

im making a whois command and I got stack when i try to get the member roles.

```
et user;

if (!args[0]) {
  user = message.member;
} else {

  user = message.mentions.members.first() || await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]).catch(err => { return message.channel.send(":x: Unable to find this member") })
}
```

//other stuff//

```
 .addField("Roles",  user.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join(' | '), true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be

```js
 .addField("Roles",  user.roles.cache.map(r => `${r}`).join(' | '), true)
```

in discord.js v12. To see all changes in v12 click [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html).